# elementary tweaks missing in Loki

Tags: themes, release-loki

I upgraded to Loki release today, and the PPA for elementary tweaks is not found. I installed it on Loki Beta 2, so I assume that it isn't configured on the server side for release. The PPA I'm trying is `ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily`

I can't use elementary OS without the dark theme, the light theme hurts my eyes and I get a migraine. Is there somewhere else to install elementary tweaks from? I'm afraid that if I can't use the dark theme, I will have to ask for my money back and use another OS :(

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there is a new version that's been updated for Loki at https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks.

First remove the old PPA as it does not work anymore and could cause problems:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
```

Then add the new PPA and install the current version of Tweaks:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. For now it looks like we can't customize the dock, hopefully this will come in a later release

Comment: I've found holding Control and right-clicking on the dock in Loki will give you a preferences menu, allowing you to customize it's look.

Comment: just type this command in the terminal to access plank settings 

"plank --preferences"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right-click the red mark right in that little corner to access plank settings.

Answer (score -2):

@ Jason Lucero,

I too was bummed that there were no basic dock configuration settings. I installed dconf-editor and found several settings to tweaks available. As you can see from the screen shot, I downsized the icons to 40px, justified the dock to the left side, changed the theme**, and enabled pressure reveal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0brt.png

** - I somehow recall liking the theme "Matte" from tinkering with elementary years ago, as I prefer a launcher/dock/bar/whatever with a background of more contrast. I just blindly entered it into dconf and it adjusted accordingly.

I noticed when I went in to ~/.config/plank/dock1 there was no "settings" text file like there was before. Previously this was available as a means to quickly adjust some dock-specific settings. While this is, for some reason, not found in Loki, at *least* the dconf entries exist in dconf-editor. :D